# Joint probability illustration on venn diagram and on a table

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I find  venn diagram and table are conflicting in terms of illustrate joint probability (table for discrete case).

Let's say for the following example: 
[image]
We know that the joint probability of X and Y is the area of intersection X and Y over the total area.

Now let's say the following table describes the joint probability of X and Y as well:
[image]

They are apparently conflicting because in the venn diagram there will always be a value of X, if given, the probability of Y is 0, since there is always a portion of X does not overlap with Y.

Because of this I have problem of understanding concept such as P(A|E1)+P(A|E2)+...=1. It is used in the proof for the concept in this post:[Proof that conditional probabilities sum up to one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084313/proof-that-conditional-probabilities-sum-up-to-one)

Since joint probability is well-defined on a venn diagram it is supposed to make sense.

Comment: You need to decide whether $X$ and $Y$ are events or random variables

Comment: @Henry can you elaborate more?

Comment: Your Venn Diagram shows $X$ and $X^c$ and similarly for $Y$, so events.  Your table has $X=1,2,3$ and similarly for $Y$ so random variables